# Simple recursive function to find missing number in a permutation

Tags: python, recursion, python-2.x

This is a short and simple Python written to help me sharpen my dulling recursion skills. It expects a sorted permutation of integers n1..n2 in list format, with a single step missing (e.g., [10,11,13]). I know it does nothing to check errors; I'm more interested in theory here.

```
from __future__ import division
from math import ceil

def f(lis):
    A = lis[:int(ceil(len(lis))/2)]
    B = lis[int(ceil(len(lis))/2):]
    ISA = sum(range(A[0], A[0] + len(A))) # "Ideal" Sum of A
    ISB = sum(range(B[0], B[0] + len(B))) # "Ideal" Sum of B
    if sum(A) > ISA:
        return f(A)
    elif sum(B) > ISB:
        return f(B)
    else:
        return B[0] - 1
```

Any thoughts on whether or not this is a decent solution? Any suggested improvements (especially in regard to time complexity)? Is there a more performant algorithm I could compare this to as a heuristic?

Comment: Does the missing step include the 2 ends of the list, or is it strictly in the middle?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand, but _strictly in the middle_, I think. If the step itself was at either end, the list wouldn't appear to have a step missing at all. I think I can safely exclude that as a special condition that would be checked for elsewhere because it would require additional information to determine which end of the list it would be found at.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. You actually don't need recursion for this problem, and you only need linear time and constant space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others pointed out in comments (and as usual), an iterative solution can be better. But you said you want to practice recursion, so I guess you want to stick with that.

This code:

> ```
> int(ceil(len(lis))/2)
> ```

Is exactly the same as:

```
len(lis) // 2
```

Because, there's no point taking the ceiling of a list length, as it's always an integer. And you can use `//` to divide and throw away the remainder, which is the same thing as casting a floating point number to integer, but shorter and simpler.

You should not duplicate code. You should put the result of the above calculation only once, save it in a variable and reuse it when creating `A` and `B`.

Similarly, instead of duplicating the logic when creating `ISA` and `ISB`, it would be better to put the common logic into a function.

Some more meaningful variable and function names would be good too.

Comment: Oops! Haha, that first point was a throwback to how I started attacking the problem at first and I didn't remove it.

Comment: I understand not duplicating code, but I felt like making a function for such a simple but specific calculation was pretty aggressive. It would add another name to the namespace that I would never use again. Do you recommend that kind of granularity for functions all the same?

Comment: Yes. But you don't have to pollute the namespace: you can define the function inside this function

Comment: Wouldn't that redefine the function at every level of recursion though? Isn't that bad form somehow?

Comment: It wouldn't redefine, and it's not bad form, it's actually encouraged

Answer (score 2):

Since we can assume without loss of generality that the missing number is not on the ends of the list, let's assume that the numbers are: `a, a+1, ..., a+k-1, a+k+1, ..., a+n`. Therefore, only `a+k` is missing from the list (but of course, we don't know what that is yet!).

For a range of integers `a, a+1, ..., b` without any missing, the sum of them is `(a-b-1)(a+b)/2`. So all we need to do is to sum all of the integers in the *given* list, and subtract that sum from the `(a-b-1)(a+b)/2`, as:

```
def findMissing(l):
    n = len(l)
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return l[0]
    # len(l) is >= 2
    a = min(l)
    b = max(l)
    fullSum = (b+1-a)*(a+b)//2
    sumInList = sum(l)
    return fullSum - sumInList

print(findMissing([10, 11, 13])) # prints 12
print(findMissing([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])) # prints 6
print(findMissing([13, 11, 12, 9, 8])) # prints 10 (even though out of order)
```

We actually don't need to sort the list because all we need are the `max` and `min` of the array, which takes linear time instead of `n log(n)` time.

In fact, this does something even stronger: find the sum of *all* missing items from the list. Of course, if there is only 1 item missing, the number returned is the missing item.

Comment: Is there a name for this approach? Also, where does the `n` come from in `n log(n)` time -- the call to `sum()`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention: `n` is the length of the list `l`. Sorting a list of size `n` in general takes `n log(n)` time.